# How to add an image?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know how I add an image in a wpf application in the c# code ?

I want to add this image :

```
<Image Name="imgRubanbleu" Source="Objet/rubanbleu.png" Height="19"
Margin="34,252,354,231" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
```

On this image :

```
<Image Source="Images/terrain.png" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" MouseUp="Image_MouseUp_1"/>
```

When I click on it...

I tried to do this :

```
private void Image_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image myImage = new Image();
        myImage.Width = 200;

        // Create source
        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
        myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"Objet/rubanbleu.png");
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();
        //set image source
        myImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
    }
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx)

But It still doesn't work...

(Sorry for my english level, I usually work in french)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: When I click on it, nothing appears...

Comment: Can you check if you are well entering inside your code? Then you also need to set uour "myImage" location maybe?

Comment: I tried MyImage.Margin but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

In code behind you need to write a full [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Objet/rubanbleu.png");

myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uri); // BeginInit/EndInit not required!
```

This only works if the image files are part of your Visual Studio project (in a subfolder named `Objet`) and their Build Action is set to `Resource`.

---

That said, your new Image control `myImage` has to be added to your UI somewhere. You seem to want to put it on top of an existing Image, so you should add it to the same container, e.g. like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="imageGrid">
    <Image ... MouseUp="Image_MouseUp_1"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void Image_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var myImage = new Image();
    ...
    imageGrid.Children.Add(myImage);
}
```

Comment: How can i see that their build action is set to Resource ?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, we tend to use XAML rather than procedural code. Here is an example of an `Image` that has it's `Source` value changed as the user moves their mouse over it:

```
<Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images\DefaultImage.png"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images\MouseOverImage.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Now I'm aware that you wanted a change after a click, but this was just an example for you to get you started. You can find out more from the [`Trigger` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. You might also like to view the [`EventTrigger` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN too... these enable us to handle events (such as your chosen `MouseUp` event) in `Trigger`s.

Comment: I just want to superimpose the first image on the second image when I click on the second image.